# Akamai APi Request is invalid., Value for filter is incorrect

Tags: api, python-requests, akamai

Here is the parameters

```
params={
'start': Start_date,
'end':End_date,
'interval': "DAY',
'objectIds': 'xxxx',
'metrics':'allEdgeHitsTotal',
'filters':[
   'url_contain': "/sample"
]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those technologies but I would check if this problem is caused by wrong string formatting - "Day' -> "Day".

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer

```
params={ 'start': Start_date,
'end':End_date,
'interval': "DAY',
'objectIds': 'xxxx', 
'metrics':'allEdgeHitsTotal', 
'filters':'url_contain=/sample' 
}
```